# How to count options in a drop down list and then randomly select

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a simple select drop down menu where it uses an index to find the selected option and select it:

```
pax_two_ob_meal = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_InFlightMeal_PassengerGridView_ctl03_mealsDropDown"))
pax_two_ob_meal.select_by_index(1)
```

I have realized that this drop down menu, can always change to include any number of values. For example it can contain 11 hot meals, or 5 sandwiches or 15 family meals. Luckily no matter which options are displayed, it is always the same id.

So my question is how can it be implemented so that python is able to count the number of options in the drop down menu and then from there randomly select an option from the list?

**Edit**

Oh and before I forget, is there a way to not include the bottom option in the count as that is a 'no thanks' option which I don't want to be part of the random selection list.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[options](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.options) will return all the options in the `<selecet>` tag. Just get the list size and subtract 1

```
options = pax_two_ob_meal.options # get all the options into list
index = randint(0, len(options) - 1) # get random number from 0 to list size - 1
pax_two_ob_meal.select_by_index(index)
```